# I am trying to find shp for zipcodes for Europe. Is there a site to find those data?

Tags: europe, postal-code

I am trying to find shapefiles, in which there are data for the zipcodes for Europe countries. Is there a site maybe that I could find the specific data?

Comment: This question made me wonder, do countries other than the US have zip codes? After all, the Wkipedia article for "zip code" specifically says that a ZIP code is a US postal code. It turns out the answer is partially yes, *some* countries have a postal code system analogous to the US ZIP code system, and those systems are sometimes colloquially referred to as zipcodes. Wikipedia has a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes. GIS stackexchange has a similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/181197/81764.

Comment: Also try the European Data Portal: https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/datasets?locale=en&tags=postcode&keywords=postcode

Comment: It looks like you can get *expensive* postal code data here: https://www.creativeforce.com/product/data-zip-codes/

Comment: It would be very useful to compile any suitable data sources for this request in a formal answer to the post.